# Make a user administrator to a sub directory site and a contributor to main site in multisite network

Tags: multisite, users, user-roles, directory

I have a multisite network. The main site displays news. The sub directory sites have administrators and I call them subsite admin. If the subsite admin wants to post to the main site, I want them to log in only as a contributor for the main admin to review their news before publishing.

Is it possible to customize the role of subsite admin where he/she may use it to login as contributor to the main site?

For example, subsite-admin-A will have 2 roles:

1. admin to its subsite
2. contributor to the main site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read User Access paragraph on the Codex here: [Multisite Network Administration](http://codex.wordpress.org/Multisite_Network_Administration)

Comment: Lone link is considered a poor answer (see [help > deleted answers](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-answers)) since it is meaningless by itself and target resource is not guaranteed to be alive in the future. Please try to include at least summary of information you are linking to.

Answer (score 1):

WordPress Multisite supports this -- see [Roles and Capabilities](http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities). Multisite's user model is that each site sets the roles for each user.

So, for example, user **Joe** can be an administrator on the *News* site and a contributor on the *Main* site, and have no role at all on the *Events* site. **Emily** can be a contributor on *News* and *Events*, and have no role on *Main*. **Ahmed** can be an editor on *News* only. **Johanna** can be an author on all three site. And so on.